# Perl regex substitutions with unicode character don't work, what am I missing?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to 'fix' some files that have unexpected unicode characters using perl's regex with the '''\N{UNICODE NAME}''' construct.  But for some reason that I don't understand fully, nothing happens, but there are no error messages.
Here is a simple test example.

```
[2007]$ read ZZ < test.txt && unum "${ZZ}"
   Octal  Decimal      Hex        HTML    Character   Unicode
    0101       65     0x41       &#65;    "A"         LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
    0341      225     0xE1    &aacute;    "á"         LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
    0334      220     0xDC      &Uuml;    "Ü"         LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
    0321      209     0xD1    &Ntilde;    "Ñ"         LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
  062745    26085   0x65E5    &#26085;    "日"         CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-#65E5, IRGKangXi=0489.010, RSKangXi=72.0, Def{sun; day; daytime}
  063454    26412   0x672C    &#26412;    "本"         CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-#672C, IRGKangXi=0509.070, RSKangXi=75.1, Def{root, origin, source; basis}
 0105236    35486   0x8A9E    &#35486;    "語"         CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-#8A9E, IRGKangXi=1163.080, RSKangXi=149.7, Def{language, words; saying, expression}
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
     061       49     0x31       &#49;    "1"         DIGIT ONE
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
 0177421    65297   0xFF11    &#65297;    "１"         FULLWIDTH DIGIT ONE
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
     057       47     0x2F       &sol;    "/"         SOLIDUS
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
     040       32     0x20       &#32;    " "         SPACE, SP
    0137       95     0x5F &lowbar;,&UnderBar;    "_"         LOW LINE
```

Now, when I try and replace one character as a test using perl inline, eg

```
[2008]$ perl -p -e 's/\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}+/X/gu;' test.txt
A á Ü Ñ  日本語 1  １  /  _
```

There's no error,  but no substitution either.  I also tried,

```
[2013]$ perl -e 'BEGIN { use charnames q{:full}; }' -p -e 's/\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}+/X/gu;' test.txt
A á Ü Ñ  日本語 1  １  /  _
```

with no change.
What am I missing, the documentation seems to imply that this should work?

If I make a direct substitution it works as expected,

```
[2015]$ perl -p -e 's/日+/X/gu;' test.txt
A á Ü Ñ  X本語 1  １  /  _
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell perl that the input is in UTF-8, and that standard output is UTF-8 too (Well, the latter can be skipped but you'll get a warning):

In a one-liner, the `-C` command line options arguments controls what's considered UTF-8: `D` tells perl to use UTF-8 as the default encoding for PerlIO channels that are opened (For both read and write; there are other options for just reading or just writing; see [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) for details), and `S` says that all standard streams (Input, output and error) are UTF-8 encoded.

So...

```sh
$ perl -CDS -wpe 's/\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}+/X/gu;' test.txt
A á X Ñ  日本語 1  １  /  _
```

Comment: You can also use `-Mmodule` to use a module instead of putting it in the body of the one-liner: `perl -Mcharnames=:full -e '...'` for example.